# PropertyChanged event fired but value hasn't changed

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a custom control dynamically created by another control, I want to change its VisualState based on the VisualState of the parent.
VisualState is a `DependencyProperty` that accept an enumerator, the control internally uses it inside the `OnPropertyChange` event to change size and internal layout.
The property are made identical on both controls (of course except the type).

```
public ControlSize VisualState
{
    get { return (ControlSize)GetValue(VisualStateProperty); }
    set
    {
        if (value != VisualState)
        {
            SetValue(VisualStateProperty, value);
        }
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStateProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(VisualState), typeof(ControlSize), typeof(CountersListControl), new PropertyMetadata(ControlSize.Large, OnVisualStateChanged));
```

The parent control dynamically allocate the component and binds its VisualState to the new control VisualState:

```
CounterControl cc = new CounterControl();
cc.SetBinding(CounterControl.ValueProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(Counter.Amount)), Source = counter, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
//cc.DataContext = this;//I tried with it, but it doesn't change a thing
cc.SetBinding(CounterControl.VisualStateProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(VisualState)), Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
```

The `Value` property binds without any issue to Counter.Amount, and looks that VisualState does too.

BUT the `OnVisualState` method is called when the parent is changed, while the children value is not.

UPDATE: I debugged the binding as suggested by @EdPlunkett, and I was getting the following message:

> Error: Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.Foundation.Int32' to type 'ControlSize';

`ControlSize` is an enumerable, so it should be able to convert it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the DataContext. This is what comes of people telling naive new XAML people to go around setting `DataContext = this` everywhere. Utter madness. Dogs and cats. My God!

Comment: Try [PresentationTraceSources.SetTraceLevel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.settracelevel(v=vs.110).aspx) to High on the misbehaving Binding, and see what you get in the debug trace at runtime.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I know, I included that comment only because in many questions I found while searching for a solution, many comment mentioned that. I just wanted to prevent such comments.

Comment: `PresentationTraceSources` doesn't seem to exists for UWP projects. And I can't find a valid substitute. Do you have any?

Comment: I haven't done UWP, but I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41692388/424129

Comment: Funny, I've read that question but I haven't noticed that answer. It helped me, I've update the question and posted an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because somehow it can't convert an `Int32` into an enumerable (even if the source is the same enumerable).

I solved creating an `IValueConverter` that converts Int32/ControlSize types and assigning it to the binding.

```
Binding visualStateBinding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(VisualState)), Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay, Converter = new ControlSizeConverter() };
```